# Can we use 2>&1 >/dev/null instead of >/dev/null 2>&1

Tags: stdout, stderr

1. Can we switch order position `2>&1 >/dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1` ?
2. Can we use `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: 1. Not without changing the behaviour; 2. Yes. But there is **many** documentation about it, please refer to it https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+redirection

Comment: Why don't you just try them out?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'die "Test stderr\n"' 2>&1 >/dev/null
perl -e 'die "Test stderr\n"' 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

Above don't work. Still show stderr.

```
perl -e 'die "Test stderr\n"' 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
perl -e 'die "Test stderr\n"' 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
perl -e 'die "Test stderr\n"' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Work well.